# Selecting ARIMA model based on PACF and ACF graphs

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

I am facing two pairs of ACF and PACF graphs. Unfortunately, I cannot use auto.arima, but I need to make sure my intuition is correct.

**1.**

[image]

**2.**

[image]

**1.** I believe that an ARIMA(1,1,0) would produce similar results. The ACF decays slowly which might suggest a unit root and the PACF cuts off after lag 1, which is a clear indication of an AR(1) process. Do you agree with this insight?

**2.** This one seems a bit more tricky to me. The ACF clearly cuts off at the second lag, which may suggest a MA(2) process. The decaying oscillation in the PACF might suggest an AR process with a negative coefficient. Due to the lack of a clear pattern here I would probably go for an ARIMA(1,0,1) or ARIMA(0,0,2) due to the oscillating and decaying PACF. Which do you think is more likely?

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the spike in the PACF *is* the unit root. This looks like a textbook ARIMA(0,1,0). Graphically, this is supported both by the slow decay in the ACF and by the fact that, reading off from the PACF, the AR(1) coefficient is very nearly equal to 1. There isn't an additional AR term. If you actually have the data (and not just a plot), try looking at the ACF of the difference; it will probably be white noise. You can also simulate several random walks and look at their ACF/PACFs, they will look just like this.

For the second set of charts, the ACF really cuts off after the first lag. You shouldn't lean too heavily on the tiny little bit of the lag-2 correlation that pokes out. This looks like a textbook example of an ARIMA(0,0,1). If you have the data, look at the ACF/PACF of the residuals after fitting an MA(1) model, you will most likely not see anything left. Also, simulate several MA(1) with $\theta\approx0.4$ and look at their ACF/PACFs, most of them will look like this.

In general, it's nearly impossible to figure out a suitable $\text{ARIMA}(p,d,q)$ model just from ACF/PACF charts of the data if more than one of $p$, $d$ and $q$ are nonzero. You can do better in multiple steps, e.g. find a difference, include it, then look at the charts for the residuals, etc. So if you're coming up with something like ARIMA(1,0,1) just by looking at those charts, it's probably wrong.