# Estimating p and q of ARIMA from the autocorrelation plot

Tags: time-series, python, arima, model-selection

I built ARIMA model, and I got the autocorrelations as in the images:

[image]

However, I could not understand which one is for $p$ and which one for $q$ and why;
my result is that $p = 1$ and $q = 2$. Am I correct or wrong and why?

Also, is there other statistical formula for finding $p$ and $q$ instead of visualization of autocorrelation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting ARIMA model based on PACF and ACF graphs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/546486/selecting-arima-model-based-on-pacf-and-acf-graphs)

Comment: The proposed duplicate is unfortunately not a general solution to the problem of estimating ARIMA orders from ACF/PACF plots, so please don't vote to close as a duplicate of that one. That said, using ACF/PACF plots to determine ARIMA orders is a highly subjective exercise and not always possible (e.g., if both p and q are nonzero - as in your case here), and modern ARIMA fitting software uses information criteria instead: [Selecting ARIMA orders by ACF/PACF vs. by information criteria](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595150/1352)

Comment: No, it is not duplicated, that question is totally different.